# EF5 "the selected stored procedure or function returns no columns"

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-5, edmx

I am using EF 5 and this is my SP

```
USE [MYDatabase] GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FirstAttend] @serviceStart date, @serviceEnd date AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SET FMTONLY OFF 

--IF (1=0) 
--BEGIN
    --SET FMTONLY ON 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #temp1

        CREATE TABLE #temp1 (id int, sid int, npi int, fiscal int, serviceStart date, serviceEnd date, fcode varchar(10), tid int, StudName varchar(200), TherName varchar (200))
        INSERT INTO #temp1

        SELECT ID,
                mand.SID,
                mand.NPI,
                FiscalYear,
                ServiceStart,
                ServiceEnd,
                FundingCode,
                ther.TID,
                RTRIM(stud.StudentLastName) + ' ' + RTRIM(stud.StudentFirstName),
                RTRIM(ther.LastName) + ' ' + RTRIM(ther.FirstName)
        FROM MandateMaster AS mand
        JOIN TherapistMaster AS ther ON ther.NPI = mand.NPI
        JOIN StudentMaster AS stud ON stud.SID = mand.SID
        SELECT *,

            (SELECT top(1) sid
            FROM SessionDetail
            WHERE SID = tb1.sid
                AND TID = tb1.tid) AS val1
        FROM #temp1 AS tb1
        WHERE ServiceStart >= @serviceStart
            AND ServiceStart <= @serviceEnd;
    END 
--  END 
END
```

and its still giving me "Stored procedure returns no columns".

I read somewhere to set the 
integrated security=True; in the connection string on web.config but still nothing worked.

I been trying to find the solutions for this but keep getting the same message. Please let me know what to do .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got nothing as result because this condition `IF (1=0)` always returns `false` then your `select` statement is never hit.

Just remove this `IF (1=0)` and your stored procedure will return some data.

Comment: I updated my code, but still the same message. check out the lines i commented out.

Comment: When you execute the stored procedure with SSMS, what you see ?

Comment: thnaks, i fixed the error, when i execute SP with exec command i was getting an error on temp database, i moved the drop DB statement at the end of the code after the select statement and it worked.